# Any CDK examples how to allow a lambda to publish to an encrypted SNS topic?

Tags: aws-cdk

I am trying to see how to publish to an encrypted SNS topic using a lambda.

The topic is KMS managed and the key is in the same stack as the lambdas (& the topic) e.g.

```
const snssqskey = new kms.Key(this, 'SQSSNSKey', {
  enableKeyRotation: true,
  description: "sqssnskey"
});
```

I have set the encryption up both via the web ui & via

```
const mainTopic = new sns.Topic(this, 'mainTopic');,
  {
    masterKey: snssqskey,
  });
```

Without encryption it all works well but with it as I get an auth error which states the key is not accessible to the lambda (even though all are in the same stack /region etc). SQS queues can subscribe happily to it using:

```
  encryption: sqs.QueueEncryption.KMS_MANAGED,
  encryptionMasterKey: snssqskey
```

So the key etc works. However having tried all sorts of policies, most recently:

```
const snspubpolicy = new iam.PolicyStatement({
      resources: [snssqskey.keyArn],
      actions: ['kms:Decrypt', 'kms:Encrypt', 'kms:GenerateDataKey*', 'kms:ReEncrypt*'],
      effect: iam.Effect.ALLOW,
    })
TestSendLambda.addToRolePolicy(snspubpolicy);
```

(having tried a resources of [*] ). I simply can not seem to get the lambda to get past the fast that it refuses on the basis the key is not accessible to the lambda with the error:

KMSAccessDenied: The ciphertext refers to a customer master key that does not exist, does not exist in this region, or you are not allowed to access

TIA

Comment: What's the status of this issue?

Answer (score 4):

The simplest answer is to add
`snssqskey.grantEncryptDecrypt(myLambda);`